# How can I set a UITableViewCell's accessory color?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'd like to set the accessory view icon to be white, similarly to how icons are colored white automatically in a black TabBar, but it's not immediately obvious to me how to do this. Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your best bet is to make an image that you want to put in there and then setting the accessory view to be that image. Here’s [Apple's Official Documentation for UITableViewCells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1).

Comment: This is waaaaay unnecessary. @believesInSanta's answer is correct.

Comment: This was actually the correct way of doing it before iOS7.

Answer (score 89):

Actually the correct answer (despite it being so late) is to set your cell tintColor property to a white `UIColor` object, like so:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [UITableViewCell new]; // or other instantiation...
[cell setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Subclassing the accessory view entirely is also possible, but the question is asking to make the cell accessory button white, so this should be the correct answer (at least for iOS7).

Note: Corrected property name, also note that it doesn't actually work for the indicator accessory type

Comment: The property on UITableViewCell is actually tintColor - not barTint.

Comment: The note about not working for indicator accessory type is what was tripping me up, good catch!

Comment: nobody uses ios6 anymore and this is still valid in ios8

Comment: At this point if it stopped working they’d be breaking a lot of people’s code it seems :)

Answer (score 7):

Setting tint color for table view solves it for me.

Answer (score 5):

```
UIImageView *checkmark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"coloredCheckmark.png"]];
cell.accessoryView = checkmark;`
```

Enjoy

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: best way to add custom image in accessory view

Comment: I too am against tinting the whole cell. This one is perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3.0**

Two ways:

1. Use your own `UIImageView` as `accessoryView` of the tableview cell.
2. If you are using the system accessory type, like `Disclosure Indicator` the arrow icon (>), you can change the `UIImageView` `tintColor` to achieve it. Like below:

   ```
   cell?.subviews.forEach({
           if let btn = $0 as? UIButton {
               btn.subviews.forEach({
                   if let imageView = $0 as? UIImageView {
                       let image = imageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
                       imageView.image = image
                       imageView.tintColor = UIColor.red
                   }
               })
           }
       })
   ```

Answer (score 3):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCustomCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as? MyCustomCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
    cell.tintColor = UIColor.white //Important
    cell.accessoryType = (someCondition) ? .checkmark : .none
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**A solution combining @BharathRao,@Hemang and @Kiattisak Anoochitarom ideas**

It seems that this a problem specially in iOS 13+ (changing `tintColor` will make no difference) with more than 2000 views on this page on Apple Developer Forums
(https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121472)

My solution using ideas from  @BharathRao and @Hemang is to add an extension to `UITableViewCell` named eg:addDisclosureIndicator

Using an extension will make things more uniform in the app specially if there are multiple tables and storyboards.

```
extension UITableViewCell {
       func addDisclosureIndicator(){
          let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 15, height: 15))
    /// 15 look great for me in iPhone and iPad
           button.setImage( UIImage(named: "rightArrow"), for: .normal) 
        ///You can download a chevron of your choice online
           button.tintColor = UIColor(yourPreferredColor)
           self.accessoryView = button

   }
 }
```

Call

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        cell.addDisclosureIndicator()

        return cell
    }
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom image / button for your accessory view, you need to change the tint color of the button something like

```
        UIImageView *trash_icon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_delete_record.png"]];
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(280, 140, 30, 30);

        //Here is where you change the color of the button.
        button.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor;

        [button setImage: trash_icon.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell.accessoryView  = button;
```

Answer (score -1):

In your custom cell class

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
   super.awakeFromNib()
   tintColor = UIColor.red
}
```

or

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellModel = addressCellModels[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:cellModel.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! AddressSelectionCell
    cell.tintColor = UIColor.red
    return cell
}
```

Comment: could it be that you override the tintcolor somewhere else?

Comment: i didn't have time so i just used a custom cell

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I would do is "create your accessory from image yourself" and change color it with template color options or just use an image that has color you want.